# I want to remove the duplicates of the list, is this possible while using the count() function in a conditional?

Tags: python, list

I made a program that removes the duplicates in a list, and my first instinct was to have a new list and then go through the first list in a for loop, while appending all of the values to this new list. Then checking in an if statement, if the count() of a specific index is greater than 2. Then to remove that value. I just want to know if I can do it with the count() function or if it has to be done the second way I did it.
This is the solution that doesn't work, but I want to figure out if its possible.

```
numbers = [9,4,4,12,12,32,24,9]
new_list = []
for i in numbers:
    new_list.append(i)
    if i in new_list.count(i) > 2:
        new_list.remove(i)
print(new_list)
```

This is the second solution that actually worked.

```
numbers = [9,4,4,12,12,32,24,9]
new_list = []
for i in numbers:
    if i not in new_list:
        new_list.append(i)
print(new_list)
```

Comment: You meant `if new_list.count(i) > 2:`, remove `i in`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You have an error in your comparison:

```
new_list.append(i)
if i in new_list.count(i) > 2:
    new_list.remove(i)
```

should be

```
new_list.append(i)
if i in new_list.count(i) == 2:
    new_list.remove(i)
```

or better: do not add and remove, but only add if not in it yet

```
if new_list.count(i) == 0:    #  if i not in new_list:  looks nicer though
    new_list.append(i)
```

Using `.count()` is inefficient.  Every time you call it, it needs to touch each list-member once. For a 100 element list of numbers 1...100 it needs to touch each element 100 times - in effect doing 100*100 checks.

---

The second approach is better, but can still be optimized. Lookup for containment inside a list is O(n) - it depends on the length of the list - use a set instead - needs some more space to store, but is way faster to lookup:

```
numbers = [9,4,4,12,12,32,24,9]
new_list = []
seen = set()
for i in numbers:
    if i not in seen:      # O(1) lookup
        new_list.append(i)
        seen.add(i)        # but takes more space
print(new_list)
```

This optimization only makes sense for lists with len 10 or so upwards - before that the usage of set, which takes time to create, will use up more time then you shave off by using O(1) lookup.

---

Consider your code:

> ```
> numbers = [9,4,4,12,12,32,24,9]
> new_list = []
> for i in numbers:
>     if i not in new_list:
>         new_list.append(i)
> print(new_list)
> ```

It loops over all numbers (8 long), touching each once - plus:

- it  would check if `9` in `new_list` (0 long), then add it to empty `new_list`
- it  would check if `4` in `new_list` (now 1 long), then add it to `new_list`
- it  would check if `4` in `new_list` (now 2 long), not add it
- it  would check if `12` in `new_list` (now 2 long), then add it to `new_list`
- it  would check if `12` in `new_list` (now 3 long), not add it
- it  would check if `32` in `new_list` (now 3 long), then add it to `new_list`
- it  would check if `24` in `new_list` (now 4 long), then add it to `new_list`
- it  would check if `9` in `new_list` (now 4 long, finding 9 at first place), not add it

up to the 2nd 9 it has to comb through all of `new_list` to see if the current number you are looking at is in it - so you need to iterate a total list length of:

- 8 (your original list) + 0 + 1 + 2 + 2 + 3 + 3 + 4 + 1 (9 is at start of list) == 24

With sets its more like:

- 8 + 1 + 1 + 1 + 1 + 1 + 1 + 1 + 1 = 16

because a set does not need to check every of its members - it simply *knows*. Now use a list with 1000 numbers from 1 ... 1000 and it gets worse and worse using lists.

Comment: So what does the set do in this case? I appreciate your help!

Comment: @JDezzy to check if `9 in [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]` you need to touch each element of the list once - worst case the 9 is not inside the list or the last element - so you need to touch 9 times. A set "knows" if something is inside it - it does not have to check its elements - so it is faster. Using a set speeds up the lookup and makes the algorithm (runtime) faster - but it takes a bit more space to store the addition set in memory.

Comment: so now with the set you created as seen. In the if statement, my list that im appending to, is drawing from the set, meaning it doesn't have to iterate through the whole list to find the value but instead drawing directly, quicker from the set? Before, I was drawing from the list and that made it go through the whole list?

Comment: Awh I see so, the regular list checks through its length, and then through it again each time it checks for a value. And set checks through its length once, and memorizes everything with that one check through, and then just grabs each value it needs? Thank you for these explanations, this is a completely new concept so its awesome you are helping me understand it so quickly.

Comment: @JDezzy Sets do not need to iterate - they are coded differently so if you check  `'something' in MySet` they can answer True/False  in constant time without checking all its elements first. A list has to check at least all its elements up to the one you look for - and if it is not in the list, it checks all its elements before returning False. If it is confusing and you have short lists, go with your 2nd attempt - should be fast enough. If you have lists with thousands/millions things in it, using a set makes it go faster.

Answer (score -1):

If you really want to use count, replace the line

```
if i in new_list.count(i) > 2:
```

with

```
if new_list.count(i) >= 2:
```

Your version is trying to check if the index i is in the count, which doesn't make sense, and then it checks if the count is greater than 2 (instead of greater than or equal to 2).

Comment: Thank you, I was just trying to see if the way I thought when I first saw the program was even possible. I am just learning so I thought maybe the syntax I was trying to use wasn't possible in a conditional. I realize the second solution is more efficient.

Answer (score -2):

Why not `list(set(list(numbers)))` ?

This will list to set (unique values) and back to list. this will work way faster than lookups for every insert element.

Comment: changes order ... for one thing.

Comment: I didn't notice any comment about solution meant to be "stable". well, sorry.

Comment: Not explicitly mentioned - but the results of above trys both are stable.